# Dual booting two different operating systems on a SSD and HDD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, dualboot

I plan to dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu for open source. Since my laptop specs are the minimal for dev work, I'm also planning to install a 250GB SSD on my laptop.

I want to ask two questions:

1. Can I dedicate whole HDD storage to Ubuntu OS and SSD to Windows OS
2. Since I have two tasks to do, what should I do first? i) Install SSD first , or
   ii) install Ubuntu before

My laptop specs are : Model - HP 15 (da0xx) , RAM - 8gb , HDD - 1tb , OS - Windows 10.

Comment: I can't comment, but possible duplicate of : [https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

Comment: @TaijasiKaveri 1.your wish,yes you can 2. install windows first( remove all drives during installation) and then install Ubuntu